Using Pydantic to define AST of boolean expressions
I'd like to use Pydantic to define and validate AST of queries that will be applied on a Pandas dataframe. Here's my code:
from typing import List, Literal, Optional, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
import pandas as pd

class ColumnCondition(BaseModel):
    """
    A class that represents a condition that is applied to a single column.
    """
    tag: Literal["ColumnCondition"] = "ColumnCondition"
    column: str = Field(..., title="The name of the column to apply the condition to.")
    operator: Literal["==", "!=", "<", ">", "<=", ">="] = Field(
        ..., title="The operator of the condition."
    )
    value: Optional[str] = Field(None, title="The value to compare the column to.")


class AndCondition(BaseModel):
    """
    A class that represents an 'and' condition that is applied to two or more conditions.
    """
    tag: Literal["AndCondition"] = "AndCondition"
    conditions: List["Condition"]


Condition = Union[ColumnCondition, AndCondition]

class ConditionModel(BaseModel):
    condition: Condition = Field(discriminator="tag")

def get_column_metadata(df: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:
    return {col: str(dtype) for col, dtype in df.dtypes.items()}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Example
    """
    condition_json = {
        "tag": "AndCondition",
        "conditions": [
            {
                "tag": "ColumnCondition",
                "column": "original_amount.currency",
                "operator": ">=",
                "value": "100",
            },
            {
                "tag": "ColumnCondition",
                "column": "original_amount.currency",
                "operator": "<=",
                "value": "1000",
            },
        ],
    }

    cond = ConditionModel.model_validate({"condition": condition_json})
    print(cond.model_dump_json(indent=2))

This works well, but I have a few questions:

Is there a way to remove the ConditionModel wrapper class? I couldn't work around it.
What is the best way to handle the types of values? should I have another field in the ColumnCondition class of its type? or maybe hold a list of columns and types?
What is the best way to convert such a condition into a string to be used in the Dataframe.query method? should I implement a __str__ in each class? or maybe write a method that traverse the AST and creates the string?


To answer your first question about the ConditionModel wrapper class, Yes, you can remove the ConditionModel wrapper by directly defining a discriminator field on the Condition union type. To do this, you need to define a custom root model using Pydantic's RootModel class or use nested BaseModel validation.
Here’s how you can do it:
from typing import List, Literal, Optional, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
import pandas as pd

class ColumnCondition(BaseModel):
    tag: Literal["ColumnCondition"] = "ColumnCondition"
    column: str = Field(..., title="The name of the column to apply the condition to.")
    operator: Literal["==", "!=", "<", ">", "<=", ">="] = Field(
        ..., title="The operator of the condition."
    )
    value: Optional[str] = Field(None, title="The value to compare the column to.")

class AndCondition(BaseModel):
    tag: Literal["AndCondition"] = "AndCondition"
    conditions: List["Condition"]

Condition = Union[ColumnCondition, AndCondition]

# Enable forward references
ColumnCondition.update_forward_refs()
AndCondition.update_forward_refs()

# Example usage without a wrapper
condition_json = {
    "tag": "AndCondition",
    "conditions": [
        {
            "tag": "ColumnCondition",
            "column": "original_amount.currency",
            "operator": ">=",
            "value": "100",
        },
        {
            "tag": "ColumnCondition",
            "column": "original_amount.currency",
            "operator": "<=",
            "value": "1000",
        },
    ],
}

cond = Condition.model_validate(condition_json)
print(cond)


Your second question; a clean approach will be to enhance ColumnCondition to include the column type. This will make validation stricter and help avoid incorrect value-type comparisons. For example;
class ColumnCondition(BaseModel):
    tag: Literal["ColumnCondition"] = "ColumnCondition"
    column: str = Field(..., title="The name of the column to apply the condition to.")
    column_type: Literal["int", "float", "str"] = Field(
        ..., title="The data type of the column."
    )
    operator: Literal["==", "!=", "<", ">", "<=", ">="] = Field(
        ..., title="The operator of the condition."
    )
    value: Union[int, float, str] = Field(
        ..., title="The value to compare the column to."
    )

Your last question, you are already looking in the right direction. You can implement a method to traverse the AST and generate a query string. A __str__ method in each class can work for individual conditions, while a central function can handle traversing and combining conditions. Example below
class ColumnCondition(BaseModel):
    # existing fields...

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.column} {self.operator} {repr(self.value)}"

class AndCondition(BaseModel):
    # existing fields...

    def __str__(self):
        return " and ".join([str(cond) for cond in self.conditions])

# Usage:
query_string = str(cond)   
print(query_string)


The example above will produce query strings like:
original_amount.currency >= '100' and original_amount.currency <= '1000'


Hope this helps.

Thanks!
For the first answer, I'm getting the error AttributeError: model_validate which is what I got when I tried it. Since Condition is a union type, it doesn't support this method.
